# results of calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors of permutation matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutation-matrices, circulant-matrices

My question is actually about the derivation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the circulant matrix. I am not good at doing that in a straight way, i.e. calculating them with a general form of circulant matrix. Instead, after reading alot, I tried calculating them of a permutation matrix $P$ which is a special case.

Let
$$P=
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{matrix}
\right],
$$
the eigenvalues of $P$ is simply given by
$$
\left|P-\lambda I \right| = 
\left| 
\begin{matrix}
-\lambda & 0        & 0        & \cdots & 0        & 1 \\
1        & -\lambda & 0        & \cdots & 0        & 0 \\
0        & 1        & -\lambda & \cdots & 0        & 0 \\
\vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots   & \ddots & 0        & 0 \\
0        & 0        & 0        & \ddots & -\lambda & 0 \\
0        & 0        & 0        & \cdots & 1        & -\lambda 
\end{matrix}
\right| = 1-\lambda^n.
$$
Then we know that the eigenvalues are simply n roots of unit of 1 which could be $\varepsilon_k=exp(\frac{2k\pi i}{n}), k=0, 1, \cdots, n-1$, i.e. $\lambda_k = \varepsilon^k, \varepsilon = exp(\frac{2\pi i} {n}$).

Later, I tried getting derivation of the eigenvectors $\mathbf{u}_k=[u_{k1}, u_{k2}, \cdots, u_{kn}]^T$ with $[P-\lambda_k I]\mathbf{u}_k=0$, i.e.
$$ [P-\lambda_k I]\mathbf{u}_k = \left[ \begin{matrix}
-\lambda_k & 0        & 0        & \cdots & 0        & 1 \\
1        & -\lambda_k & 0        & \cdots & 0        & 0 \\
0        & 1        & -\lambda_k & \cdots & 0        & 0 \\
\vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots   & \ddots & 0        & 0 \\
0        & 0        & 0        & \ddots & -\lambda_k & 0 \\
0        & 0        & 0        & \cdots & 1        & -\lambda_k 
\end{matrix} 
\right] 
\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
u_{k1} \\
u_{k2} \\
u_{k3} \\
\vdots \\
u_{k(n-1)} \\
u_{kn}
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$
This equation gives a set of formulas of $\lambda_k$
$$
\begin{matrix}
-\lambda_k u_{k1} + u_{kn} \\
u_{k1} - \lambda_k u_{k2} \\
u_{k2} - \lambda_k u_{k3} \\
\vdots \\
u_{k(n-1)} - \lambda_k u_{kn} 
\end{matrix}  = 0.
$$
By some of reference articles, one way is to assume that $u_{k1}=1$ which hence gives the first eigenvector $\mathbf{u}_0 = [1,1,\cdots,1]^T$. However, I failed to get other eigenvectors in the form of $[1, \varepsilon^{k1}, \varepsilon^{k2}, \cdots, \varepsilon^{k(n-1)}]^T$.

Comment: Why can't you see that $P[1, \varepsilon^{k1}, \varepsilon^{k2}, \cdots, \varepsilon^{k(n-1)}]^T =\varepsilon^k [1, \varepsilon^{k1}, \varepsilon^{k2}, \cdots, \varepsilon^{k(n-1)}]^T$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for reply. But how it is derived? I mean the way of calculations. It simply gets something like $\varepsilon^{-k}$ with what I did, but still seems thoroughly wrong.

Comment: I can't understand your difficulty. Multiply $P$ onto the vector and get $\varepsilon^k$ times the vector.

Comment: For me, I make myself understanding that the eigenvalues are obtained via $det(P-\lambda I)$. Then I want to calculate the eigenvectors with these eigenvalues. We should have no idea what they are before this calculation in terms of a general logic.

Comment: I found an answer in an old post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112039/eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues-of-a-permutation-matrix. What the recursive substitution means?

Comment: The definition of eigenvalue & eigenvector is that $Av=\lambda v$. The determinant calculation is secondary.

Comment: In the question you reference it means: put $v_N:=c$; then the final eqn gives $v_{N-1}$, the one above $v_{N-2}$ etc.

Comment: By the first line $\lambda u_1 = u_n$ and the 2nd line $u_1 = \lambda u_2$, we can have $u_1 = \lambda u_2$.
 And with the 3rd line, ther is $\lambda^3 u_3 = u_n$. Recursively, we come to the last line which gives $\lambda^n u_n = u_n$ ??
$\lambda^n = 1$,   $\lambda u_1 = \lambda^2 u_2 = ... = \lambda^n u_n$
 u_n=1[u1=\lambda^n-1 u2=\lambda^n-2 ... 1]

Comment: We know $\lambda$ is an $n$-th root of unity. The only solutions of the equations you have written down are multiples of of your $\epsilon$- vector.